# data.table count of rows indexing by category

Tags: r, count, data.table

I'm stuck on an easy one, but didn't find a solution in either the data.table manual or around here.

```
dt<-data.table(account=c("treu65","treu65","treg23","treg23","treg23"),year=c("2012","2013","2013","2013","2012"))
```

I need to add a column with a count of rows by account and year. The problem is that I need to create two separate columns. One will contain the count for 2012, the other for 2013.
Like so:

```
   account year count2012 count2013
1:  treu65 2012     1          1
2:  treu65 2013     1          1
3:  treg23 2013     1          2
4:  treg23 2013     1          2
5:  treg23 2012     1          2
```

Normally I would aggregate, but in this case I need the same structure as above.
I got as far as:

```
dt[year==2012,count2012:=.N,.(account)]
dt[year==2013,count2013:=.N,.(account)]
```

But I have NAs now:

```
   account year count2012 count2013
1:  treu65 2012         1        NA
2:  treu65 2013        NA         1
3:  treg23 2013        NA         2
4:  treg23 2013        NA         2
5:  treg23 2012         1        NA
```

And I should get:

```
   account year count2012 count2013
1:  treu65 2012         1         1
2:  treu65 2013         1         1
3:  treg23 2013         1         2
4:  treg23 2013         1         2
5:  treg23 2012         1         2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why `count2013` gets `1` at `treu65 2012`, but `2` at `treg23 2012`?

Comment: Because there is 1 row with account == "treu65" & year == 2013, and 2 rows with account=="treg23" & year=="2013".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the filter from `i` position (by which you will only be able to modify specific rows) to `j` position and use `sum` to count the rows:

```
dt[, `:=`(count2012 = sum(year == 2012), count2013 = sum(year == 2013)), .(account)][]

#   account year count2012 count2013
#1:  treu65 2012         1         1
#2:  treu65 2013         1         1
#3:  treg23 2013         1         2
#4:  treg23 2013         1         2
#5:  treg23 2012         1         2
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Can I ask you why the := operator is in quotation marks and what's the purpose of the square brackets at the end of the expression? (still learning..) Thanks again

Comment: Neat! +1 How about simplifying to `..., account][]` instead of `..., .(account)][]` :-)

Comment: `:=` in back ticks is a standard way to write the operator as a function that takes parameters in r. This is not restricted to `:=`, for instance you can do *\`+\`(3, 2)* for *+* as well. Back ticks is used here since you need to add multiple columns; `[]` at the end is solely for print purpose, you don't actually need it. Since `:=` modify data.table in place, by default, it doesn't print the result.

Comment: @PoGibas It's a nice simplification when there is only one group variable.